# Grep and regex - why am I escaping curly braces?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, grep, escaping

I'm deeply puzzled by the way grep seems to parse a regex:

```
$ echo "@NS500287" | grep '^@NS500[0-9]{3}'
#nothing
$ echo "@NS500287" | grep '^@NS500[0-9]\{3\}'
@NS500287
```

That can't be right. Why am I escaping curly brackets that are part of a "match the previous, N times" component (and not, say, the square brackets as well)?

Shouldn't escaping be necessary only when I'm writing a regex that actually matches `{` and `}` as literal characters in the query string?

More of a *cri de coeur* than anything else, but I'm curious about the answer.

Comment: recommend you have a look at: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Grep.html and http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Regular.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is because `{}` are special characters and they need to handled differently to have this special behaviour. Otherwise, they will be treated as literal `{` and `}`.

You can either escape like you did:

```
$ echo "@NS500287" | grep '^@NS500[0-9]\{3\}'
@NS500287
```

or use `grep -E`:

```
$ echo "@NS500287" | grep -E '^@NS500[0-9]{3}'
@NS500287
```

Without any processing:

```
$ echo "he{llo" | grep "{"
he{llo
```

---

From `man grep`:

> **-E**, --extended-regexp
>
> Interpret PATTERN as an extended regular expression (ERE, see below). 
>   (-E is specified by POSIX.)
>
> ...
>
> **REGULAR EXPRESSIONS**
>
> A  regular  expression  is a pattern that describes a set of strings. 
>   Regular expressions are constructed analogously to arithmetic
>   expressions, by using various operators to combine smaller
>   expressions.
>
> grep understands three different versions of regular expression
>   syntax: “basic,”  “extended”  and  “perl.”  In  GNU grep, there  is 
>   no difference in available functionality between basic and extended
>   syntaxes.  In other implementations, basic regular expressions are
>   less powerful.  The following description applies to extended  regular
>   expressions;  differences for basic regular expressions are summarized
>   afterwards.  Perl regular expressions give additional functionality,
>   and are documented in pcresyntax(3) and pcrepattern(3), but may not be
>   available on every system.
>
> ...
>
> **Basic vs Extended Regular Expressions**
>
> **In  basic  regular  expressions  the  meta-characters  ?,  +,  {, |, (, and ) lose their special meaning; instead use the backslashed versions `\?`, `\+`, `\{`, `\|`, `\(`, and `\)`.**

Comment: It would have saved me a lot of keystrokes to include the explanation from the manual rather than roll my own!

Comment: I received a downvote, I am not sure why. If it is because of the lack of explanation, I was updating :)

Comment: @Tom Fenech I prefer referencing the `man` page, I am not good at writing good English at a high speed :)

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. It certainly wasn't a criticism! :)

Answer (score 8):

The answer relates to the difference between Basic Regular Expressions (BREs) and Extended ones (EREs).

- In BRE mode (i.e. when you call grep with no argument to specify otherwise), the `{` and `}` are interpreted as literal characters. Escaping them with `\` means that they are to be interpreted as a number of instances of the previous pattern.
- If you were to use `grep -E` instead (ERE mode), you would be able to use `{` and `}` without escaping to refer to the count. In ERE mode, escaping the braces causes them to be interpreted literally instead.

Answer (score 1):

Instead do

```
echo '@NS500287' | egrep '^@NS500[0-9]{3}'
#                  ^
#                 /
#       notice ---
```