# Find all the direct descendants of a given commit

Tags: git, git-rev-list

How can I find all the commits that have a given commit as parent?

For instance, if I have this Git commit graph,

```
   G   H   I   J
    \ /     \ /
     D   E   F
      \  |  / \
       \ | /   |
        \|/    |
         B     C
          \   /
           \ /
            A
```

I'd like to get a list of all the direct descendants of `B` : `D`, `E` and `F`.

Comment: you are looking for "child commits", not siblings... `D` is a child of  `B`, but a sibling of `E`

Comment: You're absolutely right, english is not my native langage and I mixed up the words. That explains why Google could not help me with this question :D

Comment: you're welcome. FYI: sibling means "brother or sister"

Answer (score 6):

You can use git `rev-list --parents` and filter the children of a parent with `grep` and `awk`

```
git rev-list --all --parents | grep "^.\{40\}.*<PARENT_SHA1>.*" | awk '{print $1}'
```

Replace `<PARENT_SHA1>` with the sha-1 hash of your `B` commit.

**EDIT**

> Any time you pipe grep | awk like this, consider just using AWK alone: awk '/<PARENT_SHA1>$/ { print $1 }' should do it, for example. I would go so far as to say this is a "Useless Use of Grep", much like "Useless Use of Cat".

Thanks [shadowtalker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2954547/shadowtalker). Here is the command line that works using just awk:

```
 git rev-list --all --parents | awk '$0 ~ /^.{40}.*<PARENT_SHA1>.*/ {print $1}'
```

It's a bit shorter and one less process for the shell.

Comment: Why not use single quotes for the middle part and save the backslashes for escaping the curly braces? Easier to read, even shorter and somewhat "safer" when being extended.

Comment: @DanielBöhmer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26783219/grep-and-regex-why-am-i-escaping-curly-braces

Comment: Oh, thank you very much for enlightening me! I had actually expected that `bash` would handle curly braces specially even inside double quotes.

Comment: Any time you pipe `grep | awk` like this, consider just using AWK alone: `awk '/<PARENT_SHA1>$/ { print $1 }'` should do it, for example. I would go so far as to say this is a "Useless Use of Grep", much like "Useless Use of Cat".