# Grep Regular Expression with Alphanumeric String

Tags: regex, shell, grep

Not sure why this isn't working with Grep, although I'm knew to regex:

```
grep "[a-z0-9-]{36}" myFile.txt
```

The data inside the file looks like this:

```
ERROR for ID:e1b9bb05-323a-4128-901b-fee19beca3ba
ERROR for ID:e3e110ac-6dd1-4d5b-8320-b4281e85d76d
ERROR for ID:083753b9-479c-4307-bc7b-b48405fbf346
```

I want to match the entire Error ID, hyphens included.

Comment: Use `grep -Eo` flag

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26783219/grep-and-regex-why-am-i-escaping-curly-braces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape `{` and `}` or use Extended regular expression by enabling `-E` flag.

```
grep -o  "[a-z0-9-]\{36\}" 
e1b9bb05-323a-4128-901b-fee19beca3ba
e3e110ac-6dd1-4d5b-8320-b4281e85d76d
083753b9-479c-4307-bc7b-b48405fbf346
```

or

```
grep -Eo  "[a-z0-9-]{36}"
e1b9bb05-323a-4128-901b-fee19beca3ba
e3e110ac-6dd1-4d5b-8320-b4281e85d76d
083753b9-479c-4307-bc7b-b48405fbf346
```

Comment: I see my example was being interpreted as literal. Thanks for the clarification!